# WCF Operation parameter and return type must have datacontract attribute (always)?

Tags: wcf

could some one please confirm whether I should always have a DataContract and datamember attribute for Operation Parameter and return types?
e.g.

```
ResponseMessage getOrderDetails(RequestMessage msg)
{
  ....
}


public class ResponseMessage
{
  ...
}


public class RequestMessage
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter types and return types need to be either *serializable* or treated in a special way by WCF.

For the first case, `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` is only one way to make a type serializable - the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/02/22/536747.aspx describes the serialization programming model in WCF. As Ladislav mentioned, starting with .NET 3.5 SP1 WCF introduced a default (POCO) serialization so you don't need any annotation at all.

For the second case, there are some types which are treated as special cases by WCF, such as `System.IO.Stream` or `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` - and you can even add more such types if you use a [custom message formatter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx) (although this is an advanced scenario and not very common).

Answer (score 3):

It was required only in very first version of WCF (.NET 3.0). After that default data contract serialization was introduced so you don't have to place `DataContract` attribute on your classes and all public properties with getter and setter will be serialized. Once you want better control over serialization you will use `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes or you will switch to Xml serialization.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav Mrnka, RequestMessage and ResponseMessage are the custom classes. Are these considered POCO and are serialized by default in WCF 4.0?